# Drawing Stroke and DrawingVisual in a custom InkCanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, stroke, inkcanvas

I have a class that inherits the `InkCanvas` class. I overridden the `VisualChildrenCount` property and the `GetVisualChild` method:

```
Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        return InkCanvas.GetVisualChild(index);
    }

    return visuals[index - 1].Visual;
}


int VisualChildrenCount
{
    get { return visuals.Count + InkCanvas.VisualChildrenCount; }
}
```

Where visuals is my collection visual objects, and the `Visual` property returns a `DrawingVisual` object. 
I use this class to add and display `DrawingVisual` objects (performance reasons):

```
void AddVisual(MyVisual visual)
{
    if (visual == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("visual");

    visuals.Add(visual);
    AddVisualChild(visual->Visual);
    AddLogicalChild(visual->Visual);
}
```

The problem is the following: when I draw a new `Stroke` (in a free drawing with the mouse) this stroke is added to the InkCancas but under the previous DrawingVisual (Z-order), therefore if for example I draw the stroke under a big rectangle I can not see anything because the stroke is hidden.

How can I fix this sneaky problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the InkCanvas' `Background` property to `Transparent` (or `null`) and return the visuals in different order from the GetVisualChild override:

```
protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
{
    if (index < visuals.Count)
    {
        return visuals[index].Visual;
    }

    return base.GetVisualChild(index - visuals.Count);
}
```